# Is there a way to limit a sum up to a calculated date in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with SentDate and RefundAmounts. I would like to sum up the amounts on each row from the date until a year into the future for every line.

In the example below I would like to add a column that says sum for the year.
This sum should be for the first line the sum of refunds from '2006-12-14' until '2007-12-14' which would be 3696,22 as there were no refunds during that period.
The second row would be from '2007-12-24' until '2008-12-24' which would be 463,05

```
SentDate    YearAhead   RefundAmount
2006-12-14  2007-12-14      3696,22       
2007-12-24  2008-12-24  394,35  
2008-12-18  2009-12-18  44,33   
2008-12-19  2009-12-19  24,37   
2009-12-16      2010-12-16  21,88
```

I have tried something along the lines of

```
select SentDate, dateadd(year,1,sentdate) YearAhead, SumRefund 
from table
```

but I have no idea how to get the annual future sum for each row

Thanks for the suggestion. The final result should look as follows:

```
SentDate    YearAhead   RefundAmount    SumForYear
2006/12/14  2007/12/14  3696,22          3696,22
2007/12/24  2008/12/24  394,35           463,05
2008/12/18  2009/12/18  44,33            90,58
2008/12/19  2009/12/19  24,37            46,25
2009/12/16  2010/12/16  21,88            21,88
```

Comment: For future post and for this one, try to add expected results.

Comment: Is your table of data your expected results or the source data?  If it's the expected results, then what's the original data, and if it's the original data what's the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join with a `BETWEEN` to gather all rows that compose that period, then use `GROUP BY` with `SUM` to the result.

```
select 
    T.SentDate, 
    dateadd(year, 1, T.SentDate) YearAhead, 
    SUM(P.SumRefund) AS TotalOverYear
from 
    YourTable AS T
    INNER JOIN YourTable AS P ON P.SentDate BETWEEN T.SendDate AND DATEADD(YEAR, 1, T.SendDate)
GROUP BY
    T.SentDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suite your needs if you always need a complete year:

```
select sum(refund) as refundAmounts,year(min(SentDate)) as year from yourTable group by year(SentDate)
```

the year function gets only the year part from a datetime row and with group by you can split the aggregation of sum and min function to different groups.